# How to get my code to print the right letter count?

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote some code to print out the required number of letters inputted into a given text. For some reason after 9 letters it seems to increment by one and will slightly overshoot the number of letters given in the input. Any advice much appreciated :)

```
// Libraries
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Function to count letters
int count_letter(string text)
{
    // Declaring function variables
    int lettercount = 0;
    int number_of_letters;
    int spaces = 0;
    int letter_all;

    // Getting length of the text
    number_of_letters = strlen(text);

    // Counting the letters in the text inputted
    for(lettercount = 0; lettercount < number_of_letters; lettercount++)
       {    // If text is from a-z then count the text
            if(isalpha(text[lettercount]))
                lettercount++;
            // If text is equal to space then add up the spaces
            else if(isspace(text[lettercount]))
                spaces++;
            // Minus the spaces from the lettercount
            letter_all = lettercount - spaces;
        }

    return letter_all;

}


int main(void)
{
    // Getting a string of Text and storing it in a variable
    string passage = get_string("text: ");
    {
        printf("%i letter(s)\n", count_letter(passage));

    }

}
```

Comment: You are using the same variable as the loop variable and as the tally for counting letters. For instance you could change the loop header like so: `for(i= 0; i< number_of_letters; i++)`. And declare i in the variable list.

Comment: @hellmar Becker thanks for the suggestion. Ivé just done that. It does give me a different output but it still seems incorrect count.

Comment: Why are you subtracting the number of spaces? They would not be counted by isalpha() so this seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `letter_all = lettercount - spaces` you are subtracting the number of spaces to the number of letters. So, if you have the string "he llo" you have 5 letters and 1 space and you are doing 5-1. then your program prints 4 which is incorrect. So, you should just print lettercount  to get the letters number.

This is how your function should be.

```
int count_letter(string text)
{
    // Declaring function variables
    int lettercount = 0;
    int number_of_letters;
    int spaces = 0;
    int letter_all,i;

    // Getting length of the text
    number_of_letters = strlen(text);
    // Counting the letters in the text inputted
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_letters; i++)
       {    // If text is from a-z then count the text
            if(isalpha(text[i]))
                lettercount++;
        }

    return lettercount;

}
```

Comment: @DANNY ALEXANDER FUENTES thanks so much for the detailed explanation, really helps, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

in your function you should remove this line letter_all = lettercount - spaces which will reduce the number of actual letters

```
// Libraries
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letter(string text)
{
    // Declaring function variables
    int lettercount = 0;
    int number_of_letters;
    int spaces = 0;
    int letter_all,i;

    // Getting length of the text
    number_of_letters = strlen(text);
    // Counting the letters in the text inputted
    for(i = 0; i < number_of_letters; i++)
       {    // If text is from a-z then count the text
            if(isalpha(text[i]))
                lettercount++;
        }

    return lettercount;

}
int main(void)
{
    // Getting a string of Text and storing it in a variable
    string passage = get_string("text: ");
    {
        printf("%i letter(s)\n", count_letter(passage));

    }

}
```